# Yarn installing too many libraries

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg

I am working on a Symfony project and use Yarn to manage all my libraries. So, I have the list of the libraries in my package.json

```
package.json

 {
  "name": project,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {

     [10 libraries ...]

  }
  "engines": {
    "yarn": ">= 1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I am calling for 10 dependencies in my package.json and in my node_mdules files, I have more than 180 libraries installed...

I don't understand why it installs so many files. Moreover, those files are not additionnal libraries for the ones I use

I am using Symfony 3.4 and Yarn 1.12.3

Comment: Each dependency can have many dependencies on its own. You can check the package.json files of your dependencies in your vendor folder to see them.

Comment: Yes, I've specified it in my question : the unwanted dependencies are not from the ones I ask for :/

Comment: You're going to have to share the dependencies you're installing, which dependencies are being installed that you think are not supposed to be installed and ideally the yarn.lock file as well, please.

Comment: It's okay I've fix it, thank you :)

Comment: I'd say, that's JavaScript for you. :-D On a fresh Angular project, over 10,000 packages are installed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to reset Yarn by reinstalling it, removing all the dependencies installed locally and saving the package.json file.

Then, I've just reinstalled it and everything is ok. I had to look on the yarn.lock file, everything was installed from there, this was causing the problem.

Hope this may help someone...

Comment: Please read up on how Yarn manages dependencies. The "yarn.lock" file is not the problem. It serves a purpose, which you will find in the Yarn documentation.

Comment: Thank you but i confirm that the yarn.lock has been the problem. It has wrote unwanted dependencies, that I don't use at all and I coulded not do anything except reset yarn